# PHPMailer in Lumen API

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, lumen

I have been having trouble with sending emails via Gmail SMTP. I finally started to get somewhere by using PHPMailer.

In the controller where I am trying to send the mail I have this code at the top of the function:

```
    require_once '/var/www/html/dragonSocAPI/vendor/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
```

I get this error on the page: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPMailer' not found"
I'm guessing this means it is looking for the PHPMailer class and can't find it, but the require works so why would that not give access to the class?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you included all the other files? It looks like your'e using composer, so you don't need to use PHPMailer's autoloader.

Comment: Yes I am using composer. I ran "composer require phpmailer/phpmailer" as stated on the github readme. So you're saying I don't need that require_once line? Should it just work?

Comment: Yes, so long as you load composer's autoloader, the usual `vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: Ok so I removed the require_once line. vendor/autoload.php is being loaded in app.php so that's fine. Still getting the PHPMailer not found error though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the class name in that error: `App\Http\Controllers\PHPMailer` - it's in your namespace, so the autoloader is looking in the wrong place. Adding `use \PHPMailer;`, or `$mail = new \PHPMailer;` etc to reference the global namespace should do the trick.

[PHPMailer 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0) will introduce a namespace for PHPMailer.